# CSS/JS: Transition ignored when working with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, css, parameters, css-transitions

So, I got a button in my HTML page. When the user clicks in this button, I call a JS function that is responsible form showing a form with ID `form-dictionary` by setting its `display` property from `none` to `inline` and then the `opacity` from `0` to `1`. The change of the `opacity` property has a transition associated with it, defined at the CSS document. So, if I do it this way:

```
/* at the onClick function*/
timer= setTimeout(setOpacityDictionary,1);
```

And the `setOpacityDictionary` function:

```
function setOpacityDictionary(){
    document.querySelector("form-dictionary").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

It works fine.

But if I do this:

```
  /* at the onClick function*/
    timer= setTimeout(setaOpacity("#form-dicionario"),1);
```

And the `setOpacityDictionary` function:

```
function setaOpacity(ID){
document.querySelector(ID).style.opacity = 1;
}
```

The `opacity` is really changed, but the transition is totally ignored. Why?

PS: I know that call `setTimeOut()` for 1 ms seems something stupid, but it was necessary for a hack.

EDIT: As the fiddle isn't working, there goes a formatted version of the code (showing exactly the same problem):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>



          <!-- button to be clicked -->
        <form>
            <input type="image"  value=" Click here" id="inputDicionario"    onclick="mostraFormDicionario()" method="POST"> 
        </form>

       <!-- form that appears -->
       <form action="http://www.google.pt/search" id="form-dictionary">
          <input type="search" name="q" id="q">
          <input type="image" src="" id="form-dictionary-img">
        </form>


</body>




   <style>

    #form-dictionary{
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #2460c7;
    border:1px solid #2460c7;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin-top:3px;
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
    }

    #form-dictionary-img{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:4px;
        left:102%;
        margin-bottom:-2px;
    }

   </style>

   <script>

      var timer;

    /*There goes solution 1 (the oone that works) : */


    function setOpacityDictionary(){
        document.querySelector("#form-dictionary").style.opacity = 1;
    }


    /* Now the one that do not */
        function setOpacity(ID){
        document.querySelector(ID).style.opacity = 1;
        }

    /*now the rest of the code */
        function zeraDisplayDicionario(){
            document.querySelector('#form-dictionary').style.display="none";
        }


        function mostraFormDicionario(){
            event.preventDefault();  

            if(document.querySelector('#form-dictionary').style.opacity != "1"){
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.querySelector('#form-dictionary').style.display="inline";
                /* if you choose setOpacity Dictionary, erase the following line and replace with: 
               timer= setTimeout(setOpacityDictionary,1); */
                timer= setTimeout(setOpacity("#form-dictionary"),1); 
            }

            else{

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.querySelector('#form-dictionary').style.opacity = 0;
                timer= setTimeout(zeraDisplayDicionario,1000);
            }


        }

    </script>
      </html>
```

Comment: Can we get a fiddle?

Comment: Just a minute, I'm really trying

Comment: OK... I have a couple hours left. I'll be waiting.

Comment: The fiddle isn't working for some reason that God may know. I'm posting the formatted code.

Comment: You want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vdmbmrqa/

Comment: Yes, but with the setOpacity() method.

Comment: Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/vdmbmrqa/1/

Comment: Hmm. I wanted the transition to show always when the form appears, not only when it disappears